# Use CALENDAR_MONTH/CALENDAR_YEAR with Task.AtivityDate in SOQL Query

Tags: soql, datetime

Need your help here. I'm building a calendar to show the Due Dates of my tasks by month. My query is this:

```
SELECT Owner.Name, OwnerId, id, Subject, ActivityDate, Status  
FROM task  
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(ActivityDate) = :month_d  
AND CALENDAR_YEAR(ActivityDate) = :year_d
```

But it gives me the error:

> Error: field ActivityDate does not support date function CALENDAR_MONTH

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Due Date" field on Task or Event can not be used with those [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm). There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMeAAK) on the ideaExchange to support it.

The last comment in the idea has a suggestion for a workaround, which involves adding another date field to the Task and keeping it in sync with the Due Date field.

Comment: Yes, i already had read that to. I was just trying to find a workaround, and you helped. Thanks!